# How can I change the style of a Facebook login button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I want to apply my customer’s CSS or change the image background.

[image: Blue Facebook button with “Se connecter avec Facebook” written in it]

```
<fb:login-button length="long" size="large" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
  <span style= "margin-right: 10px;">Se connecter avec Facebook</span>
</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: You can always code your own and style it exactly as you want to.

Comment: how can i do that ? have you an example ?

Comment: You give it an id just like every other element then access it from CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Here's a question on changing style of facebook button: [Change / Hack style of Facebook 'Like it' button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752211/change-hack-style-of-facebook-like-it-button?rq=1). That post pretty much just means that facebook really doesn't want you modding their buttons, but if you want to, I guess I could help.

Just add an id or class to the button. Here's what your html might look like:

```
<fb:login-button class="fb_button" length="long" size="large" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    <span style= "margin-right: 10px;">Se connecter avec Facebook</span>
</fb:login-button>
```

And this is what your css might look like:

```
fb_button { 
    /* Your css properties */
}
```